# Angular injected pages with long content make entire page load below the top of the page, cutting off the page title

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

See how in the plunker below, when you click on `link one` or `link three`, the pages do not load at the top of the page so you cannot see the `page title`, you have to actually scroll up to see the page title. Why is this? How can I make it so it loads the page at the top, like a regular webpage?

[Here's the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mpiWuYlerWbZSclRI8cx?p=info).

Here's my js:

```
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router','ui.bootstrap']);

routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix("");
    $stateProvider


        // HOME VIEW ========================================
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'partial-home.html'
         //   onEnter: scrollContent
        })

        // ONE VIEW ========================================
        .state('one', {
            url: '/one',
            templateUrl: 'partial-one.html' 
        })

        // TWO VIEW ========================================
        .state('two', {
            url: '/two',
            templateUrl: 'partial-two.html'
        })

          // THREE VIEW ========================================
        .state('three', {
            url: '/three',
            templateUrl: 'partial-three.html'
        })
});
```

Here's my html (see the plunker link above for the injected pages).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- CSS  -->
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <!-- JS  -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <!-- // base path for angular routing   -->
    <!--<base href="/" />--> 
  </head>


<body ng-app="routerApp">


<!-- NAVIGATION -->

<!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="home">Some web page somewhere</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a ui-sref="one">Link One</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="two">Link Two</a></li> 
            <li><a ui-sref="three">Link Three</a></li>
          </ul>

        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
<!-- End Fixed navbar -->




<!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
<!--  Inject Content Here -->
<div class="container" style="padding-top:68px;">
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>





</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `autoscroll="false"` to your `ui-view` to prevent this behavior.

```
<div class="container" style="padding-top:68px;">
    <div ui-view autoscroll="false"></div>
</div>
```

[Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/LaP1yU9xtEUGJ9HISPA9?p=preview)

See [the documentation about `ui-view` and `autoscroll` directives](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-view):

> autoscroll
>   (optional)
>
> string
>
> It allows you to set the scroll behavior of the browser window when a view is populated. By default, $anchorScroll is overridden by ui-router's custom scroll service, ui.router.state.$uiViewScroll. This custom service let's you scroll ui-view elements into view when they are populated during a state activation.